# Fabric8 docker-maven-plugin unable set labels to an image

Tags: docker, maven-plugin, fabric8, docker-maven-plugin

Using the following plugin

```
<groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
<artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.33</version
```

and using the following configuration (Just posting the relevant bits here)

```
    <configuration>
      <verbose>build</verbose>
      <images>
        <image>
          <name>${container.imageNameWithTag}</name>
          <build>
            <labels>
              <dummy.label>dummyLabelValue</dummy.label>
            </labels>
            <contextDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</contextDir>
           <assembly>some required assembly </assembly>
          </build>
         </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>docker-build</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>build</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
```

But the final image has only these labels

```
        "Labels": {
            "org.label-schema.build-date": "20181204",
            "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
            "org.label-schema.name": "CentOS Base Image",
            "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
            "org.label-schema.vendor": "CentOS"
        }
```

which I reckon are from `centos` base image, but no **dummy.label**

Am I missing any configuration, or anything is wrongly configured?

The documentation to the plugin is at [Maven Docker Plugin](https://dmp.fabric8.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into [Build Configuration](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#build-configuration), of maven-docker-plugin, there is a `buildOptions` property that also could be used.

The `buildOptions` also states

> *These options map to the ones listed as query parameters in the Docker Remote API*

The query parameters in [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ImageBuild) has `labels` as a parameter.

> labels:  Arbitrary key/value labels to set on the image, as a
>   JSON map of string pairs.

So we have to specify a JSON string into build options as shown below

```
<configuration>
          <verbose>build</verbose>
          <images>
            <image>
              <name>${container.nameWithTag}</name>
              <build>
                <contextDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</contextDir>
                <buildOptions>

                  <labels>{
                    "org.label-schema.name":"${container.name}",
                    "org.label-schema.description":"My Image",
                    "org.label-schema.vcs-url":"${project.scm.url}",
                    "org.label-schema.vendor":"Test Vendor",
                    "org.label-schema.version":"${container.tag}"
                    }</labels>

                </buildOptions>
              </build>
            </image>
          </images>
        </configuration>
```